# Solr returns "No live SolrServers available" only for one specific request

Tags: solr, lucene, solrcloud

I got a perfectly fine working SolrCloud cluster.
When I try to search for "Onesie", it gives me `org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: No live SolrServers available to handle this request`
All other requests return correct sets of documents. All nodes appear to be live.
Is the word "Onesie" cursed? What kind of magic is that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There was a line in Solr `synonyms.txt` that was breaking it:

`Onesie, Baby Girl Rompers & One-pieces, Baby Boy One-Pieces`

I changed it to

`Onesie, Baby Rompers, Baby One-Pieces`

And the issue went away

Comment: Did you find what was the actual problem ?

Comment: Perhaps asterisk in synonyms file